# Hostname issue (Linux)

Tags: domain-name-system, email, hostname

I have a strange problem:
I have a mail-server. 
And I have a strange issue with hostnames on ubuntu. When I send an e-mail there is a line in the headers:  Received from domain (ip6-localhost [127.0.0.1]) but my hosts file does not have domain.com
The domain does not really fit in since domain.com was just for testing and I want to get rid of this!
/etc/hosts and etc/hostname do not have an entry for domain.com. /etc/mailname too
Any ideas? (Reverse DNS is okay)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably specified in the configuration file. Assuming this is postfix, make sure /etc/postfix/main.cf contains:

```
mydomain = yourdomain.net
myhostname = yourdomain.net
myorigin = $mydomain
```